# Redirect 404 to another domain with apache?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

Hey guys, have a question regarding apache. I have a site that's been re-engineered, but I want to capture all the 'old' links that people may have bookmarked or come from search engines to the old site which is under a new domain name. How do I get apache to redirect only 404 not found to the old site?

TIA,

J

Comment: **edit:** Thanks for the responses so far! While @seth's solution would work, looking for an apache-specific solution. 

The issue is we have OldSite, which is currently at www.example.com and moving to old.example.com, and NewSite which is going to go on www.example.com. Now I want anything that isn't on the new site (say www.example.com/oldpage.html) to go to old.example.com. The solution seems to be to have any pages not on the new www.example.com 302 to old.example.com, then have pages in neither return 404. We don't know what pages these will be in the application since it's CMS driven.

Answer (score 7):

You should first decide what status code you want to send. Sending both a 404 status code and a redirect is not possible.

But seth did already mention the right method, the [`ErrorDocument` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument):

```
# local path
ErrorDocument 404 /local/path/to/error/document
# external URI
ErrorDocument 404 http://uri.example/to/error/document
```

If you use a local path, the 404 status code is sent. If you use an absolute URI, a 302 status code (temporary redirect) is sent.

And if you want to send a 301 redirect:

```
Redirect 301 / http://new.example.com/
```

Answer (score 4):

Your old domain should capture all responses and return a '301 moved permanently' response with the new domain in the 'Location' field of the header. A 404 means 'not found' and in this case it's not strictly true.

Comment: That would work if I were redirecting to a new url, however it's the new site taking over the old url and the old site going to a different url. Putting a 301 moved permanently wouldn't work in this situation.

Comment: Ah, so you want 404 links on the new site to forward to the old site at the new domain... that makes sense but is different to how I understood your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option, similar to that proposed by @seth is to add the handler so it points to a static html page which you can use to explain to the user what happen, and present them with options.

You can include a meta redirect so that if they don't do anything after a few seconds they're automatically redirected.

Which option will work best is really up to you do decide.

Answer (score 0):

You could set your 404 document to a CGI that redirects the user.

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-bin/redirect-to-other.cgi
```